# Opensource software to create ISO file from directory on Windows

Tags: windows, open-source, iso

Is there an opensource software (CLI or GUI) to create ISO file from directory on Windows ?

So far, I've found only a free soft that does the job called [CDBurnerXP](https://cdburnerxp.se).

Answer (score 4):

FOSS will be difficult in windows native exe form, not that it may not be out there just not as common in windows world, but you *can* use linux FOSS on windows, using WSL or Cygwin. and then use something like **mkisofs**

```
mkisofs -o destination-filename.iso /home/username/folder-name
```

For CygWin

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/mkisofs.html

For WSL (Linux instructions but works the same)

https://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-ISO-File-in-Linux

if you are unfamiliar with what both are, CygWin is according to the project team: **"a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows."**

https://cygwin.com/index.html

WSL (Windows subsystem for linux) where MS says **"Developers can access the power of both Windows and Linux at the same time on a Windows machine."**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

That will make your choices on windows for FOSS on level ground!

Edit:
OP laer clarified they needed Joliet file system and used "-J -R" from the man page...

```
-J
Generate Joliet directory records in addition to regular iso9660 file names. This is primarily useful when the discs are to be used on Windows-NT or Windows-95 machines. The Joliet filenames are specified in Unicode and each path component can be up to 64 Unicode characters long. Note that Joliet is no standard - CD's that use only Joliet extensions but no standard Rock Ridge extensions may usually only be used on Microsoft Win32 systems. Furthermore, the fact that the filenames are limited to 64 characters and the fact that Joliet uses the UTF-16 coding for Unicode characters causes interoperability problems.
```

[https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkisofs#:~:text=J,causes%20interoperability%20problems](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkisofs#:%7E:text=J,causes%20interoperability%20problems)

Comment: Thanks. I installed mkisofs V3.02a09 via [scoop](https://scoop.sh) but once monted the ISO file generated contains files truncated to 8.3, so I tried `mkisofs -R` but my files are still truncated to 8.3

Comment: That is because it is defaulting to  ISO9660 which requires 8.3, mkisofs does ISO9660/joliet/hfs depending on what you specify.You need joliet file system for comparability. check out the -J option on the man page.. https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkisofs#:~:text=J,causes%20interoperability%20problems.

Comment: Thanks. `mkisofs -J -R` works fine.

Comment: excellent I will edit answer to include that, and you can accept please.